# Defining a type generic that uses an object's property as a type parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

**Summary / TL;DR:**

Is there a way to define a TypeScript generic interface that uses a value of one property as a parameter for generic type of another property?

---

**Definitions:**

I have a union type of several different interfaces that each have unique properties except for each having an 'id' property. To illustrate please consider the following:

```
interface Config1 { id: string, Config1Prop1: any, Config1Prop2: any, ... }
interface Config2 { id: string, Config1Prop2: any, Config2Prop2: any, ... }
.
.
.
interface ConfigN { id: string, ConfigNProp1: any, ConfigNProp2: any, ... }

type ConfigUnion =
  | Config1
  | Config2
    .
    .
    .
  | ConfigN;
```

I then have a type definition that pulls the keys of properties of a `Config interface` based upon the `id`, which functions as expected:

```
type ParametersOfConfig<Id = ConfigUnion['id']> = 
    Partial<keyof Extract<ConfigUnion, {id: Id}>>;
```

I attempted to use this type definition to define an object interface:

```
interface SpecificConfig<Id = ConfigUnion['id']> {
  id: Id;
  iterable: Array<ParametersOfConfig<Id>>;
}
```

---

**Expected behavior:**

I expected the interface, when implemented by an object, to infer that `Id` would be equal to the value of the `id` property such that `ConfigInstance: SpecificConfig = { id: 'Config1.id' }` would effectively evaluate its type to `SpecificConfig<'Config1.id'>`, causing `iterable` to accept only the keys of the `Config1` interface.

---

**Observed behavior:**

It, however, does not recognize this and, unless the type parameter is explicitly passed in the type definition of the object, it only allows `iterable` to accept 'id' as that's the only shared key amongst all the config interfaces.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to define the `SpecificConfig` interface to use the value of the `id`  property as the parameter for the type generic used by the `iterable` property?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be nice, but yes, it is possible if you use a helper function to incentivize TypeScript to infer the generic parameter for you. Similar to [this](https://tsplay.dev/w65MvW).